# Why is change in service not updating the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller, directive

Can someone explain why my code is not working as expected?

I expect after clicking the button, the text should be updated. But apparently, it is not the case.

I really appreciate any help.

## main.js

```
x = angular.module('app', []);

x.directive("changer", function(myService){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<button>click</button>",
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                elem.click(function () {
                    myService.item1 = 'updated';
                    scope.$apply();
                })
            }
        }
});


x.service('myService', function () {
    var item = {'item1': 1, 'item2': 2}; 

    return {
        item : item, 
    };
});

x.controller('myController', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.item = myService.item;
});
```

## main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller='myController'>
    <changer></changer>
    {{item.item1}}
</body>    
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Inside link function, shouldnt this be myService.item.item1 = 'updated'; instead of myService.item1 = 'updated'; ?

Comment: Obviously, you are right sudhir. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier and better use 'ng-click' inside your directive template please see demo below

```js
x = angular.module('app', []);

x.directive("changer", function(myService) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<button ng-click='update()'>click</button>",
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      scope.update = function() {

        myService.item.item1 = 'updated';


      }
    }
  }
});


x.service('myService', function() {
  var item = {
    'item1': 1,
    'item2': 2
  };

  return {
    item: item,
  };
});

x.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.item = myService.item;
  $scope.test = "dfsf"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller='myController'>
      <pre>{{item| json}}</pre>
      <changer></changer>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```